# Prove that $Z=\{x\in\Bbb R:$ exists $y\in\Bbb R$ with $(x,y)\in K\}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $ K \subseteq \Bbb R ^ 2 $ compact. Let $Z=\{x\in\Bbb R:$ exists $y\in\Bbb R$ with $(x,y)\in K\}$ prove that $Z$ is compact.

**Try.** Since $ K $ is compact, there is a cover $ \{P_i \} _ {i \in I} $ such that $$ K \subseteq \bigcup_ {i \in I} P_i. $$ If we take a point $ x \in A $, then exsite $ y \in \Bbb R $ such that $ (x, y) \in K \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcup_ {i \in I} P_i $. So $ (x, y) \in \displaystyle \bigcup_ {i \in I} P_i $. How could I go from there to show that $ Z $ is compact?

Comment: > Since $ K $ is compact, there is a cover $ \{P_i \} _ {i \in I} $ such that $$ K \subseteq \bigcup_ {i \in I} P_i. $$

No, this is not what "compact" means. Indeed, every subset of a topological space has at least one open cover. Instead, $K$ being compact means that each open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover. This does not assert the existence of an open cover of $K$, finite or otherwise; it just says that each time you produce an open cover of $K$, you can conclude that it contains a finite subcover.

Comment: Likewise, to show that $Z$ is compact, you will need to prove that every open cover of $Z$ has a finite subcover. So your proof should begin by choosing an arbitrary open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $Z$, and then you should proceed to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\pi\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&x.\end{array}$$Then $Z=\pi(K)$. So, since $\pi$ is continuous and $K$ is compact, $Z$ is compact too.